how to stop recursion? - java stack overflow problem
I am a student and I've been given an assignment to crack a password(n characters long, n is given in the method, all a-z). the tricky part:

no loops at all- all recursion

the only way to check if your answer is true is comparing with the entire password. cant check letter-letter

if you want to use method from the String class, you can only use the following ones: charAt, equals, length, substring.

cant use any other classes.

cant call the recursive method 26 times with each letter, in 26 different lines. when I asked my professor about this he just said "come on dude".


I already did an algorithm that covers all options for an n-length password, like so(for n=3 for example):
aaa, baa, caa ... zaa -> aaa. bba, cba, ... , zba, and so on. I am not sure it fully works now that I think about it, so if you have any notes on that it would be nice too. here it is: (note that I don't have the code for the Password class, it's a black box. the only thing I can use from it is the .isPassword() method.
public static String findPassword (Password p, int length){
        return findPassword(p, length, "");
    }
    
    private static String findPassword(Password p,int length, String str){
        if(str.length()<length){
            str+='a';
            findPassword(p,length, str);
        }
        if(p.isPassword(str)){
            return str;
        }
        return findPassword(p,length,changeString(str,0));
    }
    
    private static String changeString(String str, int index){
        if(str.charAt(index) == 'z'){
            str = str.substring(0, index) + 'a' + str.substring(index + 1);
            return changeString(str,index + 1);
        }
        return str.substring(0, index) + (char)(str.charAt(index) + 1) + str.substring(index + 1);
    }

but for the main problem: it works perfectly in 2 letter passwords and sometimes 3. the problem is that in java you can only do 2000 recursive calls until you get hit with a stack overflow, and of course for 4,5 letter passwords it will take 26^4,5 >>> 2000. the question is, how can I bypass this restriction? thought about sending it every x calls to another method, which calls back to the original method, but I couldn't figure out quite how, or if it would really worked even if I managed to do that. maybe one of y'all knows more about it? thanks in advance :)

that is one of the problems of recursive solutions... but not sure if your math is correct either (the total number of calls is not relevant, the maximum depth of recursive calls is the problem) - for example, I got 107 depth for n=4 (~(26+1)*4) or 133 for n=5 (~(26+1)*5) - but one method used (kind of simple test(int n, char ch, String guess) { if (n==0) {/* check password */ return; } /* test next position with 'a' and n-1 */ if (ch < 'z') { /* test next ch */ } })

(but I must say that I did not fully understand your algorithm - IMHO too complex)

Welcome to Stack Overflow. A [mre], please?

sorry, what do you mean by that? is the code I added not ok?

Does https://www.mycompiler.io/view/0xBvrL45cAI count? Just a bad solution with a helper method to fake a loop just to bend to the rules/restrictions. But they are calling methods recursively, I guess...

sorry, what do you mean by that? is the code I added not ok? Asking me? Sorry, I probably had not read the explanation/requirements well enough. So since you haven’t posted your Password class, I could not compile your code.

You can use a recursive search tree that is binary, where you delay the choice of a letter by passing a range of letters to choose from. At the top level of the recursion you pass a range of 0 to 25 (representing "a" to "z"), then in the next level of recursion you split the calls into a range 0 to 12 and 13 to 25. At the fifth or sixth level of recursion this "window" will have narrowed down to just one character, so then you have a string with one character. Repeat this for the next character until you have  characters.
This way the recursion depth with be like approximately 6, which is manageable.
Here is an implementation:
static String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static String findPassword (Password p, int length){
    return findPassword(p, length, "", 0, 25);
}

private static String findPassword(Password p, int length, String str, int low, int high) {
    if (str.length() == length) {
        return p.isPassword(str) ? str : null;
    }
    if (low == high) {
        return findPassword(p, length, str + letters.charAt(low), 0, 25);
    }
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    String found = findPassword(p, length, str, low, mid);
    return found != null ? found : findPassword(p, length, str, mid+1, high);
}


TL;DR: You can't. The problem you are trying to solve fundamentally cannot be done with a recursive algorithm.
But I WANNA!!!
Okay, well, let's explain which options are available to you and why they won't work.
Tail Call Optimization (TCO)
The reason you get a stack overflow in the first place, is that methods are re-entrant: Each time a method is invoked, it gets its own 'set' of variables, it doesn't 'reuse' them. If it did reuse, a method could never call itself (as it would write over its callers variables!). Separate from the re-entrant aspect requiring some memory every time you recurse for the local variables of the method, the system also needs to remember where to return to.
However, if you execute, specifically, return thisMethod(arg, arg2, arg3), then none of that is true. There is no need to save the variables, because regardless of what the recursed method ends up doing, this call does not need its variables any more. The only code that remains in this call is to just return, unchanged, what it invoked.
We don't even need to remember where to return to! Instead, we can 'shortcut' this to return directly to the caller of this method.
This is called Tail Call Optimization. If you very very carefully craft your recursive methods such that the recursion occurs in a location where [A] after returning from recursion, no variables are referred to at all, and [B] no code is executed at all other than return, then TCO can be applied and you can recurse forever, to any depth.
However, java does not support TCO. At all. You'll need to use a different platform if you want to use it.
Big stacks
You can actually control stack size. When you manually make a thread you can set it (there is a constructor that does this); if you don't (and for your default thread, the one that runs main, you obviously don't), you get the default stack size, which is controllable: You can set it with the -Xss option. You can try to make some ridiculously large stack: java -Xss1g myApp will give you a stack 1 GB large. However, password cracking like this at any non-academic length (so, 8 or more) is going to blow through that stack too. Assuming your hardware did not cost a few million, you won't have enough ram in the thing to do store this stack. And note that all the data on that stack is useless (assuming TCO could have been applied - 'java does not support TCO' means a JVM stores the variables and return point, but, it doesn't change the fact that this must-be-stored data is nevertheless pointless).
So, this solution might let you go as far as 4 characters but that's about as far as it goes.
Proper solutions
Don't use recursion. It is trivial to rewrite any recursive algorithm into a non-recursive one:

Create a class that represents the state that used to be captured in the local variables - i.e. the stuff you pass to the recursive call.
Make a single ArrayDeque or other collection that supports stack operations, and pop the initial case (as instance of that class you made) on it.
Remove the recursive call and instead encase the business logic in a while loop, that pulls the top elements off your arraydeque, adds 0 to many simpler cases on top of it, and then loops.

Often it's even simpler than that (for example, sometimes you don't need an entire class to store state; state is a single simple number for example. Or you don't need it at all), but the above is a simple easily applied formula that works for every possible recursive algorithm.
Specifically for the job of 'write a password cracker', there are vastly superior approaches, but I assume the question is more about 'lets learn how recursion works' and not actually 'write a password cracker'. Proper crackers would go very far into optimization (to a ridiculous degree; well beyond the scope of a simple SO answer, and something you should only jump into with years of programming experience), should probably involve dedicated hardware (such as GPUs which are very good of doing a simple job that has no need to communicate with any of its sibling jobs and doesn't need much memory in parallel, thousands at the same time), and should probably involve dictionaries.

first, thanks for your answer, really appreciate the help. however, it's important to mention that this assignment is for a course I am taking, so I don't have a choice about how to do it. gotta be recursion, no loops at all, that's the assignment. although I am fully aware that it will be much easier with loops instead. and from what my professor said, it is possible, as he had done it already and it worked. from what I understand the trick is trying to go to a depth of 26*n instead of 26^n, using backtracking, I just can't figure it out

You can do it with 268 recursion assuming only lowercase letters are needed. Each recursion increments the letter at its position and resets all further letters to 'a', then recurses (i.e. calls itself, and the thing it calls works on one position 'to the right'). If a recursion is at 'z', it just returns (didn't find the password). Your average stack can deal with 268 just fine.
